# How to get input from prefix and with random suffix using batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

**Question to be asked in cmd,**

`what is your name?`

**User Input,**

`my name is John`

**My Code,**

```
set /p "username=what is your name? "
if "%username%"=="my name is * " goto save
echo Invalid input && exit
:save
echo %username%>username.txt
```

**Expected Output,**

`John` to be saved in `username.txt`

Only username have to be saved in file `username.txt`. But, user input have to be like, `my name is "there name here"`

***So, there name can be anything, So, i used * , Doesn't seems to be work. Kindly help me to fix my code..***

Comment: Are you attempting to simulate a chatbot? If so, cmd is a bad idea. the workarounds to try and catch everything will be tremendous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing what I think you're doing, don't `:)` you will cause yourself a lot of frustration. Anyway.. if you are determined, then set a list of words that are not names, then replace the string by removing all the words from it. Example:

```
@echo off
set "badwords=i my name is am"
set /p "you=what is your name?"
set "you=;%you: =;%"
for %%i in (%badwords%) do call set "you=%%you:%%i;=%%"
set you=%you:;= %
echo %you:~1% & (echo %you:~1%)>users.txt
```

This example will strip out the name from the following sentences in any case presented as well as in any order:

```
I am John
my name is John
I AM JOHN
MY NAME IS JOHN
John is my name
john is I
John I am
```

obviously, you can extend your word list to exclude any additional words.

Answer (score 1):

`if` doesn't support wildcards. Workaround:

```
set /p "uname=what is your name? "
echo %uname%|find /i "my name is ">nul &&goto :save
echo invalid
goto :eof
:save
echo %uname:my name is =%>username.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `username` as a variable since it is already used by Windows.

```
@ECHO OFF
:TryAgain
SET /P "NAMEINPUT=what is your name? "
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,*" %%A in ("%NAMEINPUT%") DO (
    IF /I "%%A" == "my" IF /I "%%~B" == "name" IF /I "%%~C" == "is" (
        SET "THENAME=%%~D"
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO TryAgain
    )
)
ECHO THENAME is now "%THENAME%"
ECHO>username.txt %THENAME%
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
:again
set "uname="
set /p "uname=what is your name? "
if not defined uname goto :eof
if /i "%uname:~0,11%" == "my name is " goto save
echo Invalid input
goto again

:save
set "uname=%uname:~11%"
echo %uname%
GOTO :EOF
```

I'd echo @lit's comment...